# Push notification certificates 'invalid' despite 2015 expiration date

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Yesterday we received an email saying that a push notification failed due to an invalid certificate.  in the Settings panel, the certificate was marked as invalid.  I also noticed in the Push history that only Android and Windows phone symbols were displayed next to the latest pushes.

After looking at my certificate information via Keychain and Apple.com, I found that the expiration date was June 2015.  Rather than create another one, I just exported from Keychain and uploaded the certificate again (after deleting the one that Parse said was invalid).

The pushes appeared to have resumed... but seem a little spotty.

Additionally, I got another notice about one of the OTHER certs this morning.  Same actions, same result.

Why would certificates suddenly become 'invalid'?  Will this happen repeatedly?  Will this happen to the other 3 certificates I have uploaded?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but our certificates had NOT expired.

Comment: @HectorRamos any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from the CEO of Parse:

[@robwitman](https://twitter.com/robwitman) new type of transient errors from apple that we miscategorized

— Ilya Sukhar (@ilyasu) [August 22, 2014](https://twitter.com/ilyasu/statuses/502844457734385666)